# Cannot access python class property that starts with two underscores

Tags: python, python-2.7

code:

```
class MyEnumType(object):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    __C = 3

MyEnumType.A
MyEnumType.B
MyEnumType.__C
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    MyEnumType.__C
AttributeError: type object 'MyEnumType' has no attribute '__C'
```

Python version 2.7.17

Comment: __C is private to class , hence not accessible directly

Comment: It should work if you try like `MyEnumType._MyEnumType__C`. But I agree, the best solution is to use single instead of double underscore.